# Getting percentage of completion of child and related work items of features in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, project, workitem, agile-project-management

I am trying to get the percentage of completion of a feature based on the child work items related to the feature.

I am very new to azure devops and I have no idea where to start.

For example if I have feature with 5 related child work items, as each work item is closed, I want the percentage of items closed to be captured on the feature

Is there a way to get this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a **rollup column** to see the progress bar and count of your feature.

Please refer mentioned link for more details. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/track-the-progress-of-work-using-rollup-columns/